# Pairwise comparison of dataframe row elements

Tags: r

I want to find the number of all common elements in rows of a dataframe

```
name           members
x1            A,B,N,K,Y,G
x2            J,L,M,N,T
x3            G,H,S,J,D,F
x4            J,K,H,F,H,D,L

name         common       name
x1                   6               x1
x1                   2               x2
x1                     -             x3
x1                      -            x4
x2                       -           x1
x2                5        -          x2
x2                         -         x3
x2                          -        x4
x3                           -       x1
x3                            -      x2
x3                   6          -     x3
x3                              -    x4
x4                               -   x1
x4                                -  x2
x4                                 - x3
x4                  7                -x4
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks okay now.

Comment: Now, my problem is to generate the result below from the data above in R. Specifically, I want to generate the common figures by finding the number of intersecting elements in a pairwise manner

Comment: What is `-` standing for? x1 and x2 has only one common element which is N. So why 2 is written?

Comment: the two isnt the precise value out of the enumeration ...I gave that as an example. Also, the - is in place of number indicating the intersect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following code does what the question asks for. But note that I find it complicated, with two `merge` instructions, maybe someone else will find a simpler solution.

```
fun <- function(DF){
  ex <- expand.grid(Var2 = DF[['name']], name = DF[['name']])[2:1]
  members <- as.character(DF[['members']])
  merge(DF, ex)
}

tmp <- merge(df1, fun(df1))
o <- order(tmp[[3]])
tmp$members2 <- tmp$members[o]

tmp$common <- apply(tmp[c(2, 4)], 1, function(x){
  y1 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x[1]), ","))
  y2 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x[2]), ","))
  length(intersect(y1, y2))
})

res <- tmp[c(1, 5, 3)]
names(res)[3] <- "name2"

head(res)
#  name common name2
#1   x1      6    x1
#2   x1      1    x2
#3   x1      1    x3
#4   x1      1    x4
#5   x2      1    x1
#6   x2      5    x2
```

Final clean up.

```
rm(tmp)
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
name           members
x1            A,B,N,K,Y,G
x2            J,L,M,N,T
x3            G,H,S,J,D,F
x4            J,K,H,F,H,D,L
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it's great having you around!

Comment: ReganOdongo: Why accept my answer if @G.Grothendiek's base R is much simpler?

Comment: I actually found your code more applicable to my problem. I have tried his as well and its pretty fast but couldn't fit in my extensions.

Comment: Could you modify the output to a 4 by 4 matrix?

Comment: @ReganOdongo What do you mean, `common` as matrix entries and `x1` to `x4` as row/col names? Maybe `xtabs(common ~ name + name2, res)`.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Let me try this one out, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

**1) dplyr/tidyr** For each row, create a separate row for each member using `separate_rows` and join that to itself by `members`.  Then compute counts and complete it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  separate_rows(members) %>%
  distinct %>%
  inner_join(., ., by = "members") %>%
  count(name.x, name.y) %>%
  complete(name.x, name.y)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
   name.x name.y     n
   <chr>  <chr>  <int>
 1 x1     x1         6
 2 x1     x2         1
 3 x1     x3         1
 4 x1     x4         1
 5 x2     x1         1
 6 x2     x2         5
 7 x2     x3         1
 8 x2     x4         2
 9 x3     x1         1
10 x3     x2         1
11 x3     x3         6
12 x3     x4         4
13 x4     x1         1
14 x4     x2         2
15 x4     x3         4
16 x4     x4         6
```

**2) Base R**  Create a function which computes the number of intersections between two member components.  Then use `outer` to apply it to each pair and convert to a data.frame.

```
Scan <- function(x) scan(text = x, what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)
countSame <- function(x, y) length(intersect(Scan(x), Scan(y)))
x <- setNames(DF$members, DF$name)
as.data.frame.table(outer(x, x, Vectorize(countSame)))
```

giving:

```
   Var1 Var2 Freq
1    x1   x1    6
2    x2   x1    1
3    x3   x1    1
4    x4   x1    1
5    x1   x2    1
6    x2   x2    5
7    x3   x2    1
8    x4   x2    2
9    x1   x3    1
10   x2   x3    1
11   x3   x3    6
12   x4   x3    4
13   x1   x4    1
14   x2   x4    2
15   x3   x4    4
16   x4   x4    6
```

Although the question asked for the data.frame form above you might prefer a 2d table which can be produced by just omitting `as.data.frame.table` from the last line of code.

```
   x1 x2 x3 x4
x1  6  1  1  1
x2  1  5  1  2
x3  1  1  6  4
x4  1  2  4  6
```

**2a)** A variation on (2) which is only two lines long can be formed by applying strsplit to the members and then computing the length of the intersection of pairs using outer.  Finally we convert to a data frame.  A 2d table could again be formed by omitting `as.data.frame.table`.)

```
x <- with(DF, setNames(strsplit(members, ","), name))
as.data.frame.table(outer(x, x, Vectorize(function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)))))
```

giving:

```
   Var1 Var2 Freq
1    x1   x1    6
2    x2   x1    1
3    x3   x1    1
4    x4   x1    1
5    x1   x2    1
6    x2   x2    5
7    x3   x2    1
8    x4   x2    2
9    x1   x3    1
10   x2   x3    1
11   x3   x3    6
12   x4   x3    4
13   x1   x4    1
14   x2   x4    2
15   x3   x4    4
16   x4   x4    6
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "name           members
x1            A,B,N,K,Y,G
x2            J,L,M,N,T
x3            G,H,S,J,D,F
x4            J,K,H,F,H,D,L"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

### Update

In (2a) with R 4.3 `as.data.frame.table` could be replaced with `array2DF` .

Comment: Thanks mate, it's great having you around!

Comment: The `dplyr` way seems wrong, your base R and mine are giving the same results.

Comment: I have changed the dplyr version to only count unique elements.  All versions now give the same result.

Comment: Hi, actually want to do something very similar but I want to count repeats (ie., I want to compute a distance matrix by comparing "row1, element1", and "row2, element 1", for all elements on the row.  I plan to assign a 1 for a match, 0 for non-match. Any tips for doing that with this strategy (I am trying to avoid using a recursive for loop).